# Getting a COUNT() from a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I've got an incredibly convoluted SQL query (three INNER JOINS) that results in an easy to read result set as follows (simplified). **I have inherited the db, so it's impossible to change the structure of any of the existing tables**, and therefore I have to perform the convoluted query to get to this point:

```
product_category    |   product_code
------------------------------------
Hardware                102
Hardware                104
Hardware                102
Software                205
Software                104
```

If I then simply do a `GROUP BY` product_category, product_code, I get most of the final result set I'm interested in:

```
product_category    |   product_code
------------------------------------
Hardware                102
Hardware                104
Software                205
Software                104
```

However, what's missing is number in stock:

```
product_category    |   product_code    |   num_in_stock
--------------------------------------------------------
Hardware                102                 2
Hardware                104                 1
Software                205                 1
Software                104                 1
```

Since I want to be able to `COUNT()` directly from the processing done by the `GROUP BY` statement, I'm a little lost.

Here is the SQL query thus far:

```
SELECT categories.product_category, codes.product_code FROM stock
INNER JOIN products ON stock.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN codes ON products.code_id = codes.id
INNER JOIN categories ON codes.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY categories.product_category, codes.product_code
```

The tables are as follows:

- `CATEGORIES` - e.g., "Hardware", "Software"
- `CODES` - e.g., 100, 204 (belongs to a `category`)
- `PRODUCTS` - combinations of `categories` + `codes`, with a useless version #
- `STOCK` - entries of products, if more than one is in stock, there are multiple entries

So the reason this is so messy is because of the useless `version #` field in `PRODUCTS`. What this means is that for a particular combo (e.g., "Hardware 102") it can be entered in `PRODUCTS` multiple times, each with different `version #` values, which will then cause `STOCK` to refer to different `ids` from `PRODUCTS`, even though, to me, it's the same product. Ugh!

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

So let's say there's a product "Misc 999" that has two different versions. This means that there will an entry in `CATEGORIES` of "Misc", in `CODES` of "999" (with a `category_id` of that belonging to "Misc"), and two entries in `PRODUCTS` (both with the same `code_id` but with different `version` info - which I'm ignoring).

Then, if we have 10 of these in stock (3 of one version and 7 of the other, but I'm ignoring version info) there will be 10 entries in the `STOCK` table, each of which will refer to the `PRODUCTS` table through an `id` (two different ids, in this case).

Comment: Which column(s) and table(s) populate the quantities in stock? You should be able to `SUM()` the column (rather than `COUNT()`) to calculate the #

Comment: Well, that's the convoluted part (which I guess I didn't explain well). I've added an example to the main question.

Comment: You can do this with a sub-query. Just use a select with `SUM()` and link it with your parent table.

Comment: If products.id uniquely identifies a given products record (and codes and category are similarly uniquely identified by their id columns), you can simply add `count(*)` to your select clause. If not, it gets a bit more complicated. Can you add the primary keys for each table to your queastion?

Comment: Nice question but you need to look out with this because this can result into an 'Using temporary; Using filesort" what will slow down query execution.. even more when an disk based MyISAM table is created and is sorted (quicksort algoritm) with random Disk I/O reads and writes maybe can made an SQLFriddle off your tables and some example data?  so i can take an look into what will keep performance?

Comment: The primary key for each table is just `id`. The problem is that some products will have multiple entries in the `PRODUCTS` table, due to version info, but I want to ignore that and consider them as the same (but only if we have stock of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `count(*)` to your select clause:

```
SELECT categories.product_category, codes.product_code, count(*) qty_in_stock
FROM stock
INNER JOIN products ON stock.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN codes ON products.code_id = codes.id
INNER JOIN categories ON codes.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY categories.product_category, codes.product_code
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94771/2).

Comment: That would give me the number of total stock items I have, not the total stock I have for each product (irrespective of version).

Comment: @EleventyOne: No, it will return the total number of records (which matches the number of stock items) **within each group *for that group*** (not for the total recordset) - see this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94771/2 . Since your group includes product_code (which uniquely identifies products from your point of view), the query will return the number of items in stock for each product.

Comment: Hmm, so looking at your sqlfiddle, one difference is that you've added two codes of '999' where there would only be one (no repetition there) - as they only differ on version_info in the `products` table. Nevertheless, this ALSO seems to work on my tables, and so now I need to figure out why. I'm so lost! :)

Comment: @EleventyOne: This amended SQLFiddle should be closer to your situation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48785/1 - product ids 1 and 2 now only differ on version number. It may be clearer if you look at this ungrouped fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48785/2

Comment: Hmmm. So what if you DID want to count *all* the records that were returned, not just the specific stock-based counts that this shows, while keeping the output grouped as it is (even though that's not what I want, I think seeing how to do the alternative - that I imagined this would have done - will help me understand it better).

Comment: @EleventyOne: If you want a total count of all records returned in the whole dataset, you need to omit the group by - so you will get one row returned for the entire query. If you want to include a grouping, you can't include aggregate function results (which includes COUNT(*)) applying beyond the grouping in MySQL (although you can in other dialects of SQL, such as Oracle, SQLServer and PostgreSQL).

Comment: I see, that's very interesting. Thank you SO MUCH for your help, Mark. Seriously, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but perhaps this works:

```
SELECT categories.product_category
     , codes.product_code
     , SUM(num_in_stock) as num_in_stock
FROM (
   SELECT product_id
        , count(*) as num_in_stock 
   FROM stock
   group by product_id
   ) a
INNER JOIN products 
ON a.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN codes 
ON products.code_id = codes.id
INNER JOIN categories 
ON codes.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY categories.product_category
       , codes.product_code
```

Comment: The `num_in_stock` column is calculated from the derived table `a` in my answer.  It is the "count" of all product_id's.

Comment: Well, that seems to have worked. Now I'm just trying to figure out why :)